# T61 Thinkpad beeps when almost fully charged

Tags: battery, power, thinkpad

my Thinkpad continuously beeps when almost fully charged (like 90% charged), but when it is low on battery and charging, or not charging at all it doesn't beep. I had a similar problem in the past where it would beep when it WASN'T charging. It turned out it was some CPU setting in the BIOS; I don't remember exactly. The beeping is just a continuous beep, beep, bebeep, beep, beep, and it is very annoying. Other than that everything on it works fine.

Keep in mind, I am not too familiar with computers in terms of the bios, modules, power settings and things like that, so please, be very verbose and simplistic with your response.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps your battery is in backwards? :P

Comment: I have no idea which way it is supposed to be situated. It is a trapezoidal battery, with the angled side on the left when facing the monitor. I got it used off Ebay, and the seller said he had just replaced the battery. Would a battery put in backwards even work?

Comment: It was a joke. :) Does the battery hold any charge? If it does, is it a decent charge? The beeping issue generally stems from either a failing battery, or a failing AC adapter. Do you happen to have a spare AC adapter, or have the ability to borrow from someone that does?